# how to calculate values using COUNTIF

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have two sheets in my Excel file: `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`.

In `Sheet2` i have data with columns Severity and LodgedDate. In Severity there are multiple values like

```
sev-1
sev-2
sev-3
sev-4
```

In `Sheet1` I want to calculate the no. of occurrences for `sev-1`, `sev-2`, `sev-3`, `sev-4` for today, this month, this financial quarter, last quarter, older than last quarter.

Can anyone help?

Like

```
=COUNTIF(shee2, C2:C,"sev-1" , "Today").
```

Comment: just want to inform that row count is not constant it keep changing and LodgedDate field look something like date 3/7/2017  9:51:45 AM

Comment: Your tag seems to indicate that you are looking for a VBA solution. Yet, the text in your post shows a formula-based approach. So, what shall it be? Also, are there only four different severity levels or is this just a small sample and there may be more?

Comment: There are only 4 Severity levels with date field like 3/7/2017 9:51:45 AM(for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the date is in column B, try along the lines of

```
=countifs(Sheet2!C:C,"sev-1",Sheet2!B:B,today())
```

For the current month

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!C:C,"sev-1",Sheet2!B:B,">=1-Mar-2017",Sheet2!B:B,"<31-Mar-2017")
```

So, for a time frame enter the first and the last day of the time frame into two conditions.

You may want to use a pivot table instead of countifs formulas. It is a lot faster and won't require you to type out all the possibilities.

Comment: i have a fixed summary sheet (sheet1) with  today, this month, this financial quarter, last quarter, older than last quarter in rows and sev-1,sev-2,sev3,sev-4 in columns , so i need to calculate according totoday, this month, this financial quarter, last quarter, older than last quarter  how many different severity  calls have been raised...thats why i am not using pivot table

Comment: So, use the formulas. Anything else you need?

Comment: is there anything dynamic instead of hanging the date every quarter  like :Critiria for past Quarter
==============================
xlFilterAllYesterday
xlFilterAllThisQuater
xlFilterAllLastQuater
xlFilterAllLastYear
xlFilterAllYeartoDate


Criteria for specific Quarters
===================================
xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodQuarter1
xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodQuarter2
xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodQuarter3
xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodQuarter4

Comment: when i tried above formula it's not showing any number but only the #VALUE! appearing i used something like '=COUNTIFS(Sheet6!H:H,"sev-1",Sheet6!I:I,">=1-Mar-2017",Sheet6!I:I,"<31-Mar-2017")' as Sheet no. is 6 , Sev column is H and date is  I, can use sheet name instead of sheet no for more clarity ..

Comment: I suggested the pivot table for a more dynamic approach. Your mention of sheet name vs sheet number makes me doubt you are using this as worksheet functions. Now, please don't start posting a novel in comments. You should edit your question and provide more context in your question. A link to a sample file somewhere online would do wonders. Also clarify the VBA vs formula approach.

Comment: i am just trying to explain what i have done and what error i got...i am not a writer.

Comment: as I said: do that in your question, not in comments.